# jQuery each loop to rename every instance of an ID

Tags: jquery, each

I have a page that is creating dynamically created rows in a table with an input with an ID "fixedRate"

I am trying to rename each instance of the fixedRate id. This is only working for the first instance of the id with my current code.

Here is the code:

```
var amountRows = $("#billTasks > tr").size();
var i=1;


$("#fixedRate").each(function(){

if (i == amountRows) {
    return false; 
}
    this.id = this.id + i;
    i++;
});
```

The way I think the code should work is adding a 1,2,3,... at the end of the word fixedRate for each instance of the fixedRate ID. (i.e. fixedRate1, fixedRate2,...)

Do I need to use a while loop? I have tried many different things including a while loop and have managed to crash my browser over and over. So now I am looking for your help!

thanks!!!

Comment: IDs should be unique so `$('#...').each` does not make much sense. Try using classes instead.

Comment: An ID isn't an ID if it doesn't identify something distinctly from others.

Comment: i realize an id is unique and that is why I am trying to rename them.

Comment: The IDs have to be unique *from the start.* You can't (or at least shouldn't) use JavaScript to fix invalid code on the fly. Fix the script that's creating the elements instead.

Comment: Thanks...i think I thought they could be changed. I will back track and fix the code that is creating the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identifiers are mainly for singling out elements, if you want a wide group.
I suggest you convert the id into a class such as

```
<a class="test"></a>
```

Then you can access all elements by using the selector

```
$(".test") // gathers all elements that contain that class
```

also if you want to enumerate all the elements you can use the each function with two parameters in the callback

```
$.each($(".test"), function(a,b){
//a is the index
//b is the element
b.attr("id", a); // to set each element id to their index
});
```

Comment: I think I need more explanation. please see what I have here. It does not seem to enumerate the index.

var amountRows = $("#billTasks > tr").size();
 var i=0;
 var rateID = 'fixedRate'+i;
 
 $(".rate").each(function(){
  i++;
  $(this).attr('id', rateID);
  
 });

Comment: @mitch That's because you set the `rateID` to `"fixedRate0"` and never change it anymore. Move the `rateID = ...` line inside the `.each()` loop.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `b.id = a` would be (marginally) faster.

Comment: i think Its necessary to put $(b).attr("id", a) ir order to jquery recognize b as an object, otherwise it wont recognize as a function.

Answer (score 3):

When using the id selector, jQuery only returns the first instance.

`Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM.`

http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Since only one element is returned, your each loop only runs once.

You have two possible solutions. You can either update the logic in your script that is automatically generating the fixedRate id so that it generates unique ids or you can have that script set a class of fixedRate instead of an id. You can then loop through each class and assign a unique id to it.

```
$(".fixedRate").each(function(i) {
    var row = $(this)
    row.attr('id', 'fixedRate' + i);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps try using something akin to:

```
$('tbody tr[id^="fixedRate"]').each(
    function(i){
        this.id = 'fixedRate' + i;
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BTABN/1/).

Comment: Using identifiers as a group defeats the purpose.

Comment: While I agree with your comment, my answer was posted to address the problem the OP was having, which this seems to do quite ably. I agree wholeheartedly that using an `id` to define a group is problematic, but I'd hazard a guess the OP is cloning a table row, and then seeking to rename the cloned elements to preserve their uniqueness. Despite a class-name being more appropriate.

Comment: @Drake I'm way late on the comment here but Davids thought is now more valid than in 2011. Although it's technically not best practice, and i agree the OP should try to class them - this is still the only solution in times when you have no control over how/when/why/where the ID is assigned. Ie: Browser plugins, scrapers/static/offline, crappy SaaS "apps" where you're locked above certain template layers, dealing with constantly updated [and poorly crafted] ecom/cms mods, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work, you either have to have unique IDs in the first place.
Or instead of having `id="fixedRate"`, make it `class="fixedRate"` and use `$(".fixedRate")` instead. 
Posted a sample jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/playerace/L4szw/ , and take notice that alert only comes out once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".fixedRate").each(function(i){
    var $this = $(this)
    $this.attr('id','fixedRate' + i);
});
```

You dont need to look out for the amount of rows.

And use a class to call all the rates and then assign a id.